Rendering different component based on dropdown selection
I am working on a dashboard in which there is a main menu with multiple options. When the user selects a menu option, it will take them further to a dropdown menu. The dropdown menu will have different environments to choose from. Based on the chosen environment, the corresponding data is rendered in a table format to the user.
I am able to render the content based on the chosen environment from the dropdown menu by hard coding the environment URL for one of the environments (Prod1). To achieve the same for the other environments and avoid duplication of the same logic, I am looking for help to make the system fetch the URL dynamically based on the chosen environment from the dropdown menu.
Need experts help to achieve.Thanks in advance.
Menu.js:
  const Menu = () => {
    return (
      <div className='menu'>
          <div className='item'>
             <Stack alignItems='center' direction='row'> 
                <Typography variant='body1'>Details</Typography>
             </Stack>
             <Link to="/product">
                <Typography variant='body1'>Product</Typography>
             </Link>
             <Link to="/customer">
                <Typography variant='body1'>Product</Typography>
             </Link>
          </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

App.js:
function App () {
  const router = createBrowserRouter ([
    {
     path: "/product"
     element: <SelectEnvironment />
    },
    {
     path: "/customer"
     element: <SelectEnvironment />
    },
    { 
     path: "/account"
     element: <SelectEnvironment />
    }
  ]);
 return (<RouterProvider router={router});
}
export default App;

SelectEnvironment.js:
function SelectEnvironment() {
   const[environment, setEnvironment] = useSate ("selectEnvironment");
   const[prod1DetailsVisible, setProd1DetailsVisible] = useSate (false);
   const[prod2DetailsVisible, setProd2DetailsVisible] = useSate (false);

   const handleOnChange = (event) => {
    setEnvironment(event.target.value);
   }

   useEffect (() => {
     environment === 'prod1' ? setDevDetailsVisible (true) : setDevDetailsVisible(false);
     environment === 'prod2' ? sitDetailsVisible (true) : sitDetailsVisible(false);
   }

   return (
      <div className='environment selection'>
        <div>
          <Typography variant='body1'> Select </Typography>
        </div>

        <div className='environment list'>
          <select className='form select' value ={environment} onChange={handleOnChange}>
             <option value='selectEnvironment'>select</option>
             <option value='prod1'>PROD1</option>
             <option value='prod2'>PROD2</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        {prod1DetailsVisible && < ProductTable/>}
        {prod2DetailsVisible && < ProductTable/>}
     </div>
    )
}
export default SelectEnvironment;

ProductTable.js:
   function ProductTable() {
       const dispatch = useDispatch();
       const list = useSelector((state) => state.product.products);
       
       useEffect (() => {
          dispatch(getProduct ());
       },[]);

       return (
          <>
            <Grid container>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <TableContainer component ={paper}>
                  <Table sx={{mnWidth:650}} aria-label='simple table'>
                    <TableHead>
                       <TableRow>
                          <TableCell>
                            <b> Product Id </b>
                          </TableCell>
                          <TableCell>
                            <b> Product Name </b>
                          </TableCell>
                       </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>
                    <TableBody>
                       {
                         list.map((row) => (
                           <TableRow key={row?.id}>
                              <TableCell component='th' scope='row'>{row?.id}</TableCell>
                              <TableCell >{row?.name}</TableCell>
                           </TableRow>
                       ))}
                    </TableBody>
                  </Table>
                </TableContainer>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </> 
       );
   }
   export default ProductTable;

Customer.js
function CustomerTable() {
       const dispatch = useDispatch();
       const list = useSelector((state) => state.customer.customers);
       
       useEffect (() => {
          dispatch(getCustomer ());
       },[]);

       return (
          <>
            <Grid container>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <TableContainer component ={paper}>
                  <Table sx={{mnWidth:650}} aria-label='simple table'>
                    <TableHead>
                       <TableRow>
                          <TableCell>
                            <b> Customer Id </b>
                          </TableCell>
                          <TableCell>
                            <b> Customer Name </b>
                          </TableCell>
                       </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>
                    <TableBody>
                       {
                         list.map((row) => (
                           <TableRow key={row?.id}>
                              <TableCell component='th' scope='row'>{row?.id}</TableCell>
                              <TableCell >{row?.name}</TableCell>
                           </TableRow>
                       ))}
                    </TableBody>
                  </Table>
                </TableContainer>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </> 
       );
   }
   export default CustomerTable;


store -> action -> index.js
    export const getProduct = () => (dispatch) => {
         fetch ("Product URL").then ((response) => response.json())
         .then((data) => {
           dispatch ({type:GET_PRODUCT, payload:data}); 
         }) 
         .catch(error) => console.log(error));
     };

     export const getCustomer = () => (dispatch) => {
         fetch ("Customer  URL").then ((response) => response.json())
         .then((data) => {
           dispatch ({type:GET_CUSTOMER, payload:data}); 
         }) 
         .catch(error) => console.log(error));
     };

store->reducer->type.js
  const initialState = {
     products :[];
  };
  
 const initialStateCust = {
     customers :[];
  };

  const product = (state=initialState, action) => {
       switch(action.type) {
          case GET_PRODUCT:
              return {...state, product: action.payload};
        }
   };

   const customer = (state=initialStateCust, action) => {
       switch(action.type) {
          case GET_CUSTOMER:
              return {...state, customer: action.payload};
        }
   };
 export default product;



Seems like a lot of code to wade through and still not understand what your post is about. Can you [edit] to clarify what the exact specific question/problem/issue is and start with the minimal amount of code necessary to constitute a [mcve]?

@DrewReese: Updated. Please check and let me know if you have any questions.

And the code? Is that the minimal code? Seems to me to be a bit of a code dump. What specific part do you need readers to look at or focus on? What part do we start with to work through whatever flow you have an issue with?

This can be easily done by using a hashmap method, where you just need to fetch the data and apply to the map. See the example below.


// mock data

const links = [
  {
    title: 'Services',
    url: '/Services',
    submenu: [
      {
        title: 'Cloud',
        url: '/services/cloud',
      },
      {
        title: 'SEO',
        url: '/services/seo',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: 'Who we are',
    url: '/about',
  },
]

 // Map the data and apply to the links

{links.map((items, index) => (
        <li key={index}>
          <a href={items.url} onClick={linkClick}>
            {items.title} <ArrowIconForward />
          </a>
        </li>
      ))}




What is a "hashmap method"? Can you [edit] to expand on this idea, explain what it is and how it's applied, and include a more complete and relevant code example?
